# @Transactional does not work if exception is thrown

Tags: java, mysql, spring, jpa, spring-boot

This is my spring boot application:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableTransactionManagement(proxyTargetClass=true) 
public class WhizhopApplication {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    SpringApplication.run(WhizhopApplication.class, args);
 }
}
```

This is my service:

```
@Service
public class OrderService {
  @Autowired
   BillRepository billRepo;

    @Transactional(rollbackFor = Exception.class)
    public BaseDTO saveKot(BillDTO billDto) {
     try {
        //business logic
        billRepo.save();
     } catch (Exception e) {
TransactionAspectSupport.currentTransactionStatus().setRollbackOnly();
        
    }
   }
}
```

If any exception occurs, the transaction is not rolled back.

Comment: You are using MySQL make sure you are using InnoDB tables and not MyISAM tables. (The latter doesn't support transactions!).

Comment: Why are you manually trying to rollback the transaction?

Comment: since I'm using try catch. the exception will be handled successfully. So I have to manually rollback

Comment: Shouldn't you be throwing the exception out of the method and handling it outside instead? It would be better design and you'd get rid of your ugly code in the method.

Comment: The issue is resolved. My Mysql engine was MyISAM, I changed to InnoDB now its working fine

Comment: My problem was just a little bit different. It was not working until I changed from import javax.transaction.Transactional to import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional ... and from just @Transactional to @Transactional(rollbackFor = Exception.class). I hope it can help someone.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't catch exception if you want it to be processed with `@Transactional`.

Also please note that:

1. `@Transactional` works only for public methods
2. [Spring’s @Transactional does not rollback on checked exceptions](https://www.catalysts.cc/wissenswertes/spring-transactional-rollback-on-checked-exceptions/)

Answer (score 0):

Extract business logic into separate method annotated by `@Transactional(rollbackFor = Exception.class)` and remove annotation from `saveKot`.

```
public BaseDTO saveKot(BillDTO billDto) {
    try {
        businessLogic(billDto);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // catch if it needed but manually rollback is not needed
        return null;
    }
}

@Transactional(rollbackFor = Exception.class)
BaseDTO businessLogic(BillDTO billDto) throws Exception {
    // It will be automatically rolled back if Exception occurs
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By default rollback from @Transactional is happen only for Runtime execption, if you want to change this behavior you can add `rollBackFor` parameter to annotation

@Transactional(rollbackFor={MyException.class})